# Powershell script that can be run on NinjaOne that will identify whether added machines have particular filepath/file present

Tags: powershell, automation, path, ninja

I'm in need to create a PowerShell script that can be run via NinjaOne automation on all added machines that will look for the presence of two file paths and then output a list of machines that have the file paths present.

The paths being

```
C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\deinstall
C:\app\client\product\12.2.0\client_1\deinstall
```

I don't really know where to start so was wondering if someone could help :)

Haven't really tried as don't know where to begin.

Just need a list of machine names that have the filepaths :)

Answer (score 0):

A suitable approach is outlined in this [NinjaOne blog post](https://www.ninjaone.com/blog/how-to-check-if-a-path-exists-using-powershell/). The script presented there requires a custom field (or two in your case) to store the result of the check:

```
Set-IfPathExists.ps1 -Path "C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\deinstall" -CustomField "OracleCDrive"
```

ThisCheck if the path exists on the machine and sets the custom field "OracleCDrive" to "Yes" if the folder exists or "No" if it doesn't.